# Issue in moving the rectangle up and down in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I tried to move a rectangle in Pygame using arrow keys. I'm able to move it left and right but it does not move up and down. If i press the down key it grows in y direction rather than moving.
Here's the code

```
    import pygame , sys
    from pygame.locals import *

    catx = 10
    caty = 10
    screen =0

    def myquit():
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    
    def event_input(events):
        global catx,caty, screen
    
        for event in events:
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            else:
                if event.type== KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key== K_ESCAPE:
                        myquit()
                    elif event.key== K_RIGHT:
                        catx+=5
                    elif event.key==K_LEFT:
                        catx-=5
                    else:
                        pass
                elif event.type== KEYUP:
                    if event.key== K_DOWN:
                        caty+=5
                    elif event.key== K_UP:
                        caty-=5
                screen.fill((0,0,0))
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,255,255),(catx,50,50,caty))
                pygame.display.update()
    
    
    def main():
        global screen
        pygame.init()
        screen_width=640
        screen_height=500
        pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Move Rectangle")
        screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
        pygame.display.update()
    
        while True:
            event_input(pygame.event.get())
    
    main()
```

Comment: Seems like the program is checking whether key up/down was pressed, when the key press is released: `elif event.type== KEYUP`. What happens if you check it in the `if event.type== KEYDOWN` clause?

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the height of the rectangle rather than the position. Arguments for pygame.rect are `(x, y, width, height)`, but your arguments are passed as though the arguments were`(x, width, height, y)`, so it changes the height of the rectangle rather than y. Replace line

`pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,255,255),(catx,50,50,caty))`

with

`pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,255,255),(catx,caty,50,50))`

Comment: Thanks I got that. I did some rookie mistake I guess 